# What goes in the id/BTCUSD field for Mt. Gox "submit an order" API call?

Tags: mtgox, api

I am trying to place a new order using Mt. Gox's [submit an order](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1#Submit_an_order) API call. However I keep on getting the error object

```
{ result: 'error', error: 'Bad API call' }
```

I'm fairly certain I'm doing everything right, except I suppose the order Id which is referred to as BTCUSD in the documentation.

```
https://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/private/order/add
```

It gives no other explanation on what this field is, and I have found other projects calling it ID, so I'm using the node-uuid `v1()` method to generate a unique ID for the field.

So this is the URL I create:

```
/api/1/36c1f990-a4a4-11e2-84fd-a100a9f27dd2/private/order/add
```

and the object I send with it

```
{ type: 'ask', amount_int: '100000.000', price_int: '20000000' }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This field is used to spcify the currency pair type of the return data, so leaving in `BTCUSD` works fine or changing it to a different accepted currency pair, such as `BTCEUR`, also works and just changes the currency denomination of the returned data.